# Profiling memory consumption of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, profiling, ants

I have my styles and templates defined in multiple xaml files. I have one xaml file called `colors.xaml` which is just a resource dictionary with colors and brushes. All other files reference this resource dictionary.

After reading this:

http://wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html

I realized I'd have mutliple instances of colors.xaml file, which wasn't performant. I profiled the application with ANTS profiler with SharedResourceDictionary and without it. Results were there, less ResourceDictionary instances, and much less colors and brush instances as well.

I wanted to try something else, reference certain xaml files more than once, 
and see if the elements are loaded more than once (since I'm loading the same xaml files twice).

Colors and Brushes are loaded multiple times (expected), however I other xaml files I also have defined a number of styles and control templates, but they don't get instantiated more than once (even if I load the same xaml file multiple times).

Can anyone explain this to me maybe.